# displaying query result on the page via php

Tags: php, mysql

connection to the database

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','') OR die('ERROR :'.mysqli_connect_error());
```

over here i am using 3 tables,

- farm(farm_id, taluka, village,cropgrown)
- interest(id_interest, talukainvest, villageinvest, cropgrowninvest)
- registration (reg_id,name,....)

i want to output **name, taluka, village, crop grown**

where taluka=talukainvest, village=villageinvest, cropgrown=cropgrowninvest

and i want this to display in a table form kind of on the php page using browser.

```
       $z  = "SELECT f.farm_id, 
            r.name,
            f.village,
            i.talukainvest,
            i.cropgrowninvest
        FROM
            farm f
                JOIN interest i
        ON f.village = i.villageinvest
                JOIN registration r
            ON f.farm_id = r.reg_id
        WHERE f.taluka = i.talukainvest AND
              f.cropgrown = i.cropgrowninvest";


    $y = mysqli_query($dbc,$z);
    $x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($y);

    if ($x) {

            echo 'id  :'.$x['farm_id'].'name :'.$x['name'].'village :'.$x['village'].'taluka :'.$x['talukainvest'].'crop grown :'.$x['cropgrowninvest'] ;
        }   

        else{
            echo'queries error'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        }
```

i tried to test this but its not working.

is there any alternate way than what i have done?if this is not efficient.
newbie learning and you guys are helping alot in this.

Comment: Please describe what "It's not working" looks like.

Comment: @darwin theres some mistake in query i think so. its throwing me in the else loop where i have echo the error.

Comment: You're getting an error message? That's important. What does the message say?

Comment: 'queries error' thats it!  mysqli_error($dbc) function is not showing anything

Comment: That suggests the query is succeeding but not selecting any data. What happens if you enter the query directly into `mysql`?

Comment: in mysql it is not showing my database in which i am working but it reflects on phpmyadmin

Comment: i think theres some problem in query. can you help me out with similar type or query? or a query which can satisfy my requirements @darwin

Comment: Could you post a few rows of data from each table? Three or four each should do, but make sure it's data that *should* produce a result.